# Applying a function over a column in an r data frame where each item is a character string

Tags: r, function, char, apply, sapply

I have a dataframe, wineSA, with two columns. One of these columns is populated with a character string, like so:

```
> summary(wineSA$description)
   Length     Class      Mode 
   129971 character character
```

An example of a typical entry would be:

```
review <- "Aromas include tropical fruit, broom, brimstone and dried herb. The palate isn't overly expressive, offering unripened apple, citrus and dried sage alongside brisk acidity."
```

I also have a function, that when applied to a string returns a sentiment score, like so:

```
> Getting_Sentimental(review)
[1] 0.4317412
```

I want to apply this function to every element in the wineSA$description column and add the sentiment score, as a separate column, to the data frame wineSA.

I have tried the following method, which uses apply(), but I get this message:

```
> wineSA$reviewSentiment <- apply(wineSA$description, FUN = Getting_Sentimental)
Error in apply(wineSA$description, FUN = Getting_Sentimental) : 
  dim(X) must have a positive length
```

I'm not sure apply() is appropriate here, but when I use either sapply() or lappy() it populates the new column with the same value for the sentiment.

Is there a special way of handling functions on string characters? Is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks

Comment: Try `sapply(wineSA$description, Getting_Sentimental)`.

Comment: `Apply` requires an array (e.g. data frame) or matrix. The error `dim(X) must have a positive length` is in reference to the fact that `dim(wineSA$description)` is `NULL` because `wineSA$description` is a vector.

Comment: @Kelli-Jean I see, so how should I change my code? maybe use `wineSA[,description]` instead?

Comment: @nicola `sapply()` does work! The issue is it's incredibly slow; I have just under 130,000 rows of data. Reducing this to 13,000 still takes a couple of minutes to process. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @RichardCollins 1) The point is that you don't use `apply` for vectors. `apply` is for matrices and higher dimensional arrays. 2) I guess that it's not that `sapply` is slow by itself; very likely `Getting_Sentimental` is. If you want more speed, you should try to vectorize or optimize your function.